# Rational solutions of $k^4(x^2+4)-4xk^2=z^2$, where $k$ is given rational.

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, parametrization

How to generate some parametric family of rational solutions to $k^4(x^2+4)-4xk^2=z^2$, where $k$ is given rational.

Comment: LHS is a perfect square.  Perhaps you can simply it.

Comment: It's a quadratic in $x$, try solve for x in terms of $k$ and $z$ and then can parametrise

Comment: One of the solutions is $\frac{\sqrt{-k^4(4k^4-z^2-4)}+2k^2)}{k^4}$. What after this? I want discriminant as perfect square.

Comment: What restrictions,if any, are on $z$?

Comment: Discriminant should be non-negative, this might put some condition on $z$?